# Go Sha256Sum Difference with Bash sha256sum

Tags: bash, go, sha256

My go code is producing different sha256sum values than bash commandline. **I've read through various questions and answers and they all point to what I've already done, as this community asks me to do before posting**

Here's my sha256sum code on `go`

```
sha256Key:=verifyEmail+":"+md5password+":"+dateStr
hasherSha256 := sha1.New()
hasherSha256.Write([]byte(sha256Key))
sha256Val:=hex.EncodeToString(hasherSha256.Sum(nil))
```

And here's my `bash` script code:

```
key=$( echo -n "$verifyEmail:$md5PWD:$pwTime" | sha256sum)
echo $key
```

Ive already validated that the keys are the same. One note, my dateStr variable inside go comes from date formatting:

```
now := time.Now().Unix()
rem := now % 3600
date := now-rem         
dateStr:=strconv.FormatInt(date,10)
```

Usually I get downvotes so I tried making this question as clear and concise as possible.

Please let me know if im missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/#example_Sum256

Comment: @nbari i appreciate it i actually realized mid post of question that i was using sha1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you want to calculate SHA-256 checksum, yet you do:

```
hasherSha256 := sha1.New()
```

That will be an SHA-1 hasher, not SHA-256. Instead do:

```
hasherSha256 := sha256.New()
```

Also note that to calculate a "one-time" digest of some data (ready in a byte slice), you may use the [`sha256.Sum256()`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/#Sum256) function like this:

```
digest := sha256.Sum256([]byte(sha256Key))
```

Note that here `digest` will be an [array](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) (not a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), in Go they are quite different), an array of type `[32]byte`. To obtain a slice "of it" (of type `[]byte`), slice it like this:

```
digestSlice := digest[:]
```

Comment: Thats funny you mention that i just figured that out.